# Trouble with forming a regex pattern.

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a multi-line document, from which I have to extract a specific part.

> ID: 58101 \n LOCATIONS: Yerevan, Armenia \n
>   _info:  Aregak was established in 1997 by United Methodist Committee on Relief, an international NGO is headquartered in New-York, NY, USA.
>   In 2006 Aregak UCO CJSC obtained license to carry out full range
>   credit services in Armenia. The organization operates in ten marzes of
>   Armenia and throughout Nagorno Karabakh. Aregak Head Office is located
>   in Yerevan. \n START_DA: 28 November 2013

Now this is what I ame up with "^_info:(\n|.)*START_DA:" Problem is it highlights start_da as well. I want to make it like whatever the word there is if it detects a ":" at the end of the word, (START_DA:) stop and not include that word. So my target is in layman terms from _info: to ..headoffice is located in Yerevan. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `START_DA:` part of a [positive lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) expression instead:

```
^_info:(\n|.)*(?=START_DA:)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I spent 2 days trying to figure this out! Appreciate it

Comment: What if I want to say the word can be anything and not just STAR_DA but all the words will end with a  : is that possible? So instead of START_DA: if I have HEY: or anything really

Comment: Sure. You can use `^_info:(\n|.)*?(?=\w+:)` instead then.

Comment: Hi Blhsing one question about  that regex you made: ^_info:(\n|.)*?(?=\w+:) 
Let's say the end line has START DA without the underscore, how do I handle that? Because when I try this code it kinda highlights START as well! Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Simply removing underscore from that regex should work, i.e. `^_info:(\n|.)*(?=START DA:)`